# How to find the template of a Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio

I have a VS Solution with multiple projects of different types.
Is there a quick way to know the VS template used to create a project.

I would like to know if it is a `Console app` or `ASP.NET MVC` or `ASP.NET Core` or `Class library` etc.

Could not find that in project properties. It only shows "Output type", which can be same for class library/mvc projects and console/.net core projects.

Using VS 2019

Comment: Although the template author could add some identification information, most Project Templates are not identified so you cannot find what was the template that lead to the project. FWIW, Project Templates are located in something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates` see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-custom-project-and-item-templates

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with Roslyn is limited to [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.outputkind?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.2.0)

And here's a little Console app that takes in a solution file and spits out some basic info with the `OutputKind`

```
// install packages
// - Microsft.Build
// - Microsft.CodeAnalysis.Csharp.Workspaces
// - Microsft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.outputkind?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.2.0

using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

var solutionFile = @"C:\repos\MySolution.sln";

using var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionFile);
var projects = solution.Projects;

foreach (var project in projects)
{
    var name = project.Name;
    var language = project.Language;
    var kind = project.CompilationOptions.OutputKind;

    Console.WriteLine($"Project: {name}, Language: {language}, Kind: {kind}");
}
```

But then, I stumbled on something far more accurate! This [list of known project type GUIDs](https://tekeye.uk/visual_studio/microsoft-visual-studio-project-type-guids-and-project-guids#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%20Project%20Type%20GUIDs%20and%20Project,%20%20%7B349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21%7D%20%2029%20more%20rows%20) could potentially be parsed from the solution file and matched with a well-known GUID and appears to be the identification you're looking for.

Edit: [This list](https://www.newbedev.com/visual-studio-project-type-guids#:%7E:text=Here%27s%20a%20list%20of%20project%20type%20GUIDs%3A%201,MVC%205%20%2F%20Web%20Application%20More%20items...%20) Is way better

Comment: I tried the console. I had a Blazor project where one of them was Blazor server and the rest were class library projects. The output says all are ConsoleApplications!!
I tried to get the guid like this - `project.GetType().GUID` and this `ec49469e-f94d-3fca-8142-e06d19f75d4c` is not matching with any in the links provided.

Comment: Yep, technically blazor/aspnetcore apps _are_ console apps. It's not a perfect mechanism. But I agree with you, Visual Studio itself somehow is able to tell a blazor project apart from a console app, and it displays an icon with a small globe (web) in the solution explorer.